Error when Loading js file in HTML. HTML unable to load my js file
I tried loading js code in html but no js functionality is reflected in my code.
here is my html snippet
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
<head>
Point Of Sale

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="plugins/chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link href="plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script> 
<link href="css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="./js/pos.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/product-filter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/print-js"></script>

</head>`

Here is my js snippet
 import path from 'path';
import moment from 'moment';
//import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import Store from 'electron-store';
import { remote } from 'electron';
import btoa from 'btoa';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import JsBarcode from 'jsbarcode';
import macaddress from 'macaddress';
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
import './renderer.js';

    let cart = [];
let index = 0;
let allUsers = [];
let allProducts = [];
let allCustomers = [];
let allCategories = [];
let allTransactions = [];
let sold = [];
let state = [];
let sold_items = [];
let item;
let auth;
let holdOrder = 0;
let vat = 0;
let perms = null;
let deleteId = 0;
let paymentType = 0;
let receipt = '';

let totalVat = 0;
let subTotal = 0;
let method = '';
let order_index = 0;
let user_index = 0;
let product_index = 0;
let transaction_index;
//let host = 'localhost';
let host = 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx';

let port = 'xxxx';


let dotInterval = setInterval(function () { $(".dot").text('.') }, 3000);


// Define the path to the uploads directory within the current directory

//let api = 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/rms/api/';
let api = 'https://' + host + '/rms/api/';

let categories = [];
let holdOrderList = [];
let customerOrderList = [];
let ownUserEdit = null;
let totalPrice = 0;
let orderTotal = 0;
let auth_error = 'Incorrect username or password';
let auth_empty = 'Please enter a username and password';
let holdOrderlocation = $("#randerHoldOrders");
let customerOrderLocation = $("#randerCustomerOrders");

let settings;
let platform;
let user = {};

let by_till = 0;
let by_user = 0;
let by_status = 1;
if (typeof remote !== 'undefined') {
    // Code that uses remote
    const app = remote.app;
//let img_path = app.getPath('userData') + '/POS/uploads/';
const img_path = path.join('undefined','POS', 'uploads/');
const currentDirectory = __dirname;
let storage = new Store();
let start = moment().startOf('month');
let end = moment();
let start_date = moment(start).toDate();
let end_date = moment(end).toDate();
}
$(function () {

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + '  -  ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    

});


$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

The html details are displayed as well as the styling but the pos.js is not showing up. the pos.js contains the functionality. I also tried creating a http-server to see if it works but nothing worked
This code runs well in electron js. what i did, I refactored the code to see if it will work on browser but nothing works
in my console in browser, i get this
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module pos.js:1:2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/js/pos.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/js/pos.js”. index.html:22:45
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/js/login.js:7
login.js:7:33
Source map error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js
Source Map URL: /sm/3a884fe0bdb97cb3a94b410e67cf38fdc248890d5581232077b3e6241e25cd21.map

Source map error: Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/css/bootstrap.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

Source map error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: file:///home/harry/React/Store-POS/MyPOS/www/plugins/dataTables/pdfmake.min.js
Source Map URL: pdfmake.min.js.map


put the base jQuery library file (this one: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) before all other js files. then your other JS code will start working.

import needs a filename with the extension.

Your HTML seems highly invalid.

@Death-is-the-real-truth They have import $ from 'jquery' so they're not getting it from the jquery script tag.

Your title starts with "Error when Loading js file". Where are the details of the error you see?

I've edited the question and I have posted the error I get after trying the above solutions

you are mixing js modules with plain js scripts which generally not desired and can easily break. an issues i see is at the top,  import statements should not preceded by any code, like your window.$ definition.

browsers wont resolve npm packages for you, use import-maps with a cdn. many packages you reference needs polyfills because they are node built-ins like path. the electron package is electron exclusive, good chance you wont be able to polyfill. and im guessing you will need to start a webserver on localhost to serve the es module imports with proper mimes and cors policy.

Can't see the opening tag for </head>. Please include that and try again.
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Your scripts here--->
    </head>
</html>


I've edited the question. the html is still not loading my js file

This isn't really an answer. Next time, could you place a comment instead?

<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
</head>
    <body>
 Your HTML content here 
</body>
</html>


This isn't really an answer. Next time, could you place a comment instead? –

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
